# Can anyone help me identify this insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I'm trying to identify the insect below that I found in Edmonton, Alberta, Canada. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Where was it found?

Comment: Edmonton AB, Canada

Comment: Also, what type of environement was it found in? Forest, grass, in the basement, etc...?

Comment: it was flying in my garage while the door where open. I assume it's terrestrial but I'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 7):

This a long-horned [caddisfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caddisfly) ([gallery](http://bugguide.net/node/view/5233/bgimage)), which belongs to the superfamily [Leptoceridae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leptoceridae), though, due to a combination of the quality of your image, as well as <s>limited</s> available resources online, I'm currently not able to confidently suggest a genus or species. At any rate, here are a few pictures of various caddisfly that resemble the characteristics of your posted insect.

---

*Unkown genus & species*
[image]

*Ceraclea dissimilis*
[image]

*Ceraclea sp.*
[image]

*Ceraclea slossonae*
[image]

From where the majority of what I believe to be the closest matches mostly all belong to the genus *Ceraclea*, I am currently leaning towards that, however, I will continue to search for further validation.